# calculate percentile and use case when in sql

Tags: sql, case, percentile, percentile-cont

I have a data set

Cashback table

```
user   | order_amount
-------+------------
raj    | 200
rahul  | 400
sameer | 244
amit   | 654
arif   | 563
raj    | 245
rahul  | 453
amit   | 534
arif   | 634
raj    | 245
amit   | 235
rahul  | 345
arif   | 632
```

I want to calculate the percentile of each user order amount

and If the percentile of any user's order amount is more than 80 percentile then return 'Yes' else 'No' in new column Big_spender means he is one of the top spenders

output will look like

```
user   | percentile | Big_Spender
-------+------------+------------
raj    | 50         |     NO
rahul  | 40         |     NO
sameer | 84         |     YES
amit   | 85         |     YES
arif   | 96         |     YES
```

Comment: average of order amount

Comment: Please describe how to calculate the `percentile`

Comment: can you please be more specific? lets take ```arif``` as an example - his order sum is 1829, num of order is 3 and average per order is 609.667. with that information how you calculate the percentile

Comment: sorry average will not be used ,median will be used

Comment: @LandLord even if it median, you didn't explain how to calculate the percentile. if we go back to ```arif``` example now the median is 632? how did you get percentile  of 96?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
SELECT
    id,
    USER,
    SUM(order_amount),
    total_sum.total,
    ROUND(
        (SUM(order_amount) / total * 100)
    ) AS percentage,
    CASE WHEN ROUND(
        (SUM(order_amount) / total * 100)
    ) > 80 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as Big_spender
FROM
    new AS t1
JOIN(
    SELECT
        SUM(t2.order_amount) AS total
    FROM NEW AS
        t2
) AS total_sum
GROUP BY
    USER
```

Comment: This is for percentage I think not for percentile